# HTML table showing one of the Column empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a HTML table with JSON data,but one of my column is shows up as empty.
The column which is showing empty  is actually an input field whose data i am getting from back end

Who my table is working on buttons click:-

- Firstly my table is not rendering `quantity` column
- after that user inputs something inside input field and clicks on view he only gets to see the rows where he/she has provided input
- then after if user clicks on edit he/she will get to the main table so that user can enter input again
- **important :**  `itemsQuantiry1` is to store the values  user enter into input fields and again if user clicks edit all the data user has entered will be there in input field

```js
var tableData1 = [{
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Selling Price": "68.0000",
    "Quantity": "2596.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1409",
    "Item Name": "Puliogare",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Quantity": "3698.0000"
  }
]
var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTable1(tableData1) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData1[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData1.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData1[i][col[j]];
      if (tableData1[i]['Item Code'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData1[i]['Item Name'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData1[i]['Selling Price'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData1[i]['Quantity'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } // i think here i am missing somthing in else

        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

  $(".dataReset").focus(function() {
    $("#loadDraft").hide();
    $("#saveDraft").show();
  });
  $(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
    itemsQuantiry1[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
  });
}

addTable1(tableData1);


function viewData() {
  //get all quantity input fields
  var quantityFields = document.getElementsByClassName("dataReset");
  //iterate through all quantity input fields
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
    if (quantityFields[i].value != 0) {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is not equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to visible
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to collapse
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //changing the value of the select menu to "All"
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').hide();
  $('#edit').show();
}

function editData() {
  addTable1(tableData1);
  $('#view').show();
  $('#edit').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">

    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save
    </button>
      <button id="clear" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i>Clear
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="view" class="commonButton" onclick="viewData()">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>View
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="edit" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display: none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Edit
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="loadDraft" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Load Draft
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="saveDraft" class="commonButton" style="display: none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save Draft
    </button>



    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

In my code i think i am missing something at **line no.70**

Comment: @Fzstyle have you run my snippet...initially i am populating table from JSON data where one of my column not gets populated,

Comment: The problem is with the condition **if(itemsQuantiry1[i])**. itemsQuantiry1 will be empty initially. You are updating only on change of input. May be you no need to add if there while creating the table.

Comment: Or you can push the values in to itemsQuantiry1 array, while creating the table.

Comment: @RakeshMakluri how can you help me with small snippet

Comment: Did you try removing if condition?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the if condition you are checking with itemsQuantiry1 array. It is empty while you are creating the table. So, it will never go inside the if condition to assign the value to input.

Either you can push Quntity in to itemsQuantiry1 array while creating the table or you can remove if condition.

If you want to push, update the 2nd for loop, just add the line itemsQuantiry1[i] = tableData1[i].Quantity; at the start of the for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableData1.length; i++) {
    itemsQuantiry1[i] = tableData1[i].Quantity;

    // your remaining code here.
  }
```

Comment: Can also change `quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);` Since `itemsQuantiry1[i]` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is missing,

`quantityField.setAttribute("placeholder", tabledata);`

For the first problem list.

```js
var tableData1 = [{
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Selling Price": "68.0000",
    "Quantity": "2596.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1409",
    "Item Name": "Puliogare",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Quantity": "3698.0000"
  }
]
var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTable1(tableData1) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData1[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData1.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData1[i][col[j]];
      if (tableData1[i]['Item Code'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData1[i]['Item Name'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData1[i]['Selling Price'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData1[i]['Quantity'] === tableData1[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } // i think here i am missing somthing in else
        quantityField.setAttribute("placeholder", tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");

  $(".dataReset").focus(function() {
    $("#loadDraft").hide();
    $("#saveDraft").show();
  });
  $(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
    itemsQuantiry1[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
  });
}

addTable1(tableData1);


function viewData() {
  //get all quantity input fields
  var quantityFields = document.getElementsByClassName("dataReset");
  //iterate through all quantity input fields
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityFields.length; i++) {
    if (quantityFields[i].value != 0) {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is not equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to visible
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      //if the input value of this quantity field is equal to zero then find the closest "item-row"
      //so that we can set this table row to collapse
      quantityFields[i].closest(".item-row").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //changing the value of the select menu to "All"
  $('#CategoryName').val('All');
  $('#view').hide();
  $('#edit').show();
}

function editData() {
  addTable1(tableData1);
  $('#view').show();
  $('#edit').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">

    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save
    </button>
      <button id="clear" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-eraser"></i>Clear
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="view" class="commonButton" onclick="viewData()">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>View
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="edit" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display: none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Edit
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="loadDraft" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Load Draft
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="saveDraft" class="commonButton" style="display: none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save Draft
    </button>



    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: got that in place of place holder i should have put value like `quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);`